# date_format() on sql query gives error Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Original SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM date WHERE fecha > now() AND feriado != 1 Limit 10
```

I want to format returned dates to '%d %b %y' using SQL date_format() but i get error **#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)** when using
 `SELECT DATE_FORMAT((SELECT * FROM date WHERE fecha > now() AND feriado != 1 Limit 10), '%d %b %y')`
Can you give me advice on how to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. The first operand would be one column (field). In your query you have a sub-select query instead. Also, you are selecting all columns in that table. Date_Format should be on just the one date field in that table. Also, if you use a reserved word for a table or column name, you need to put it inside back tics `

Comment: @SloanThrasher Luckily `date` isn't a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `DATE_FORMAT()` around specific column names.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d %b %y') AS formatted_date
FROM date
WHERE fecha > NOW() and feriado != 1
LIMIT 1
```